# How to have 4 div around one centered div?

Tags: html, css, transform

I have centered a yellow div horizontally and vertically like this:
`<div style="position:absolute;width:830px;height:590px;background:yellow;left:50%;top:50%;transform:translate(-50%, -50%);"></div>`
I would like to have 4 div around the centered div, so one div on the left side, one div on the right side, one div above and one div below, each should touch only one border of the view-port, and each should touch one border of the centered div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO the easiest way would be to use `CSS-Grid`. Then you can sepcify the placement either definet through the `grid-column` and `grid-row` placement or by using `grid-area`.

To let the elements (divs)  touch one border of the viewport, you need to define the height of the grid to `100vh`. Also you need to remove the default `body margin`

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    ". top ."
    "left center right"
    ". bottom .";
}

.center {
  grid-area: center;
}

.top {
  grid-area: top;
}

.right {
  grid-area: right;
}

.bottom {
  grid-area: bottom;
}

.left {
  grid-area: left;
}


/* for demo purpose only */
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container > div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px dashed black;
  min-height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="center">Center</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The solution above shows a grid with the same size of grid items. The complete solution of the question with the code mentioned on the top of this webpage is: a) add in .center `width:830px;background:yellow;`, and b) add in .container `grid-template-rows: 1fr 590px 1fr;`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that other answer is better, but here will an alternative:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: purple;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.upper-row,
.middle-row,
.bottom-row {
  flex: 1;
}

.upper-row .inner-row {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 100%;
}

.middle-row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.middle-row .inner-row {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.middle-row .inner-row:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}

.bottom-row .inner-row {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="upper-row">
    <div class="inner-row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle-row">
    <div class="inner-row"></div>
    <div class="inner-row"></div>
    <div class="inner-row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-row">
    <div class="inner-row"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kdsv99/140w56th/16/

Comment: Please use a [repro] (`<>`-Button or `Ctrl + M`) to post your code. This will be runaable and makes the use of a codepen, jsfiddle or simliar obsolete in enarly every case. Answers must be self-containing and as such should not relay on external resources.

Answer (score -1):

If you are doing it to learn, first stop use style on html, but include a css file and second for that matter you should look into flexbox property or grid.
You can use display flex create a container with display:flex; that contain 3 elements div1 your div and div2, then inside div 1 and 2 you create other 2 divs and give them display:flex; flex-direction: row; a 25% width ; height auto;
your div should have a width of 50%

Comment: the answer is way to broad, technical incorrect (there is no need to use external CSS. head style is just fine) and will not give the intended layout. Answer misses a [repro] that would add great value and validate your answer.

Comment: My bad, i didn't understand the question. Anyway is always better use css and one should learn it to not get bad habits.

Comment: Head style is CSS. There are different use cases and both are fine to use. Head style is not bad habbits. CSS is faster as it can eb cached at the second time. Also it can be sued for multiple pages. Head style takes lower space and has a higher specificty weight. Some cases dont even allow the use of external CSS.